# Salvamento de arquivo no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, arquivo, phpmyadmin

Estou com uma aplicação aonde um cliente pode criar um ***Contrato*** através de um formulário e armazenar as informações no banco. Ai dentro desse sistema eu criei um botão de editar, aonde ele ira puxar todas informações daquele contrato por um SELECT no banco. Com isso o usuário poderá cadastrar um arquivo por um input file (pdf e etc). Teria alguma forma de salvar o arquivo + uma variável (por exemplo: O numero do Contrato que é único, o que evitaria duplicação de arquivo)

```
<form action="saveEdit.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="arquivo">
        
  
  
      <div class='label'>
      <div>Numero do Contrato:</div>
            <div>
              <input type='text' id='' data-ls-module="charCounter" maxlength="8" name = 'numContrato' value="<?php echo $numContrato?>" readonly/>
            </div>
      </div>

          

      <div class='label'>
          <div>Data Inicio:</div>
                <input type="date" id="birthday" name="dataInicio" value="<?php echo $dataInicio?>">
            </div>
      
      <div class='label'>
          <div>Data Final:</div>
                <input type="date" id="birthday" name="dataFinal" value="<?php echo $dataFinal?>">
            </div>
      
      <div class='label'>
      <div>Responsável:</div>
                <input type="text" id='' data-ls-module="charCounter" maxlength="30" name = 'responsavel' value="<?php echo $responsavel?>"/>
            </div>
      
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Ativo:
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" value="1"  <?php echo $ativo == '1'  ?"checked":"teste2"; ?> id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" name= 'ativo'>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
      
      

        
      <input type="hidden" name="idContrato" value=<?php echo $id;?>>
      <button class="btnSalvar" type = "submit" name= "update" id="submit">Salvar</button>
      <a href="contrato.php"> <button class="btnSalvar">Cancelar</button> </a>
      </div>
      </div>
 
    </form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Tens que criar uma pasta para colocar os ficheiros submetidos e no ficheiro saveEdit.php obtens o nome do ficheiro e a extensão para concatenar com o número do contrato para definir o ficheiro que vais gravar.

Depois copias o ficheiro para a pasta com a função move_uploaded_file() e fazes um UPDATE no SQL com o caminho do ficheiro e o resto dos dados.

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES["arquivo"])) {
  $arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
  $numContrato = $_POST["numContrato"];
  $path = pathinfo($_FILES["arquivo"]["name"]);
  $name = $path['filename'];
  $ext = $path['extension'];
  $target_dir = "uploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . $name . $numContrato . "." . $ext;

  $dataInicio = $_POST["dataInicio"];
  $dataFinal = $_POST["dataFinal"];
  $responsavel = $_POST["responsavel"];
  $ativo = isset($_POST["ativo"]) ? 1 : 0;
  $idContrato = $_POST["idContrato"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
  $sql = "UPDATE contratos SET arquivo = '$target_file', numContrato = '$numContrato', dataInicio = '$dataInicio', dataFinal = '$dataFinal', responsavel = '$responsavel' ativo = '$ativo' WHERE id = '$idContrato'";
  $conn->query($sql);
}
?>
```